# GNU Parallel Memory Leak when Running Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, gnu, temporary-files, gnu-parallel

I have a python script that uses a function to temporarily downloads files from a bucket, transforms them into an `ndarray`, and concludes by saving it (final size ~ 10GB) to another bucket.

I need to run this script ~200 times, so I created an sh file, `run_reshape.sh`, to parallelize the runs that follows this layout:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
python3 reshape.py 'group_1'
python3 reshape.py 'group_2'
...
```

I have been trying to parallelize these runs using `GNU Parallel` in the following way:

```sh
parallel --jobs 6 --tmpdir scratch/tmp --cleanup < run_reshape.sh
```

After 2-3 successful runs of the .py script on different cores, I get the following error from `GNU Parallel`:

```sh
parallel: Error: Output is incomplete. Cannot append to buffer file in $TMPDIR. Is the disk full?
parallel: Error: Change $TMPDIR with --tmpdir or use --compress.
```

I'm not sure how the disk could be full. When I check `free -m` after `parallel` throws the error, I have >120GB of available space on disk.

I have checked both `.parallel/tmp/` and `scratch/tmp/`. `scratch/tmp/` is empty and `.parallel/tmp/` has a 6 byte file in it. Also all variables within the python script are located inside a function that is called without its own variable assignment. As an extra precaution, I also delete them and call `gc.collect()` at the conclusion of `reshape.py`.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

---

**Extra Info**

In case it's helpful here is the basic outline of `reshape.py`:

```py
# Define reshape function
def reshape_images(arg):
    x_len = 1000

    new_shape = np.empty((x_len, 2048, 2048), dtype=(np.float16))
    new_shape[:] = np.nan

    for n in range(x_len):              
        with gcs_file_system.open(arg+str([n])+'.jpg') as file:
            im = Image.open(file)
            np_im = np.array(im, dtype='np.float16')
            new_shape[n]=np_im
            del im
            del np_im

    save_string = f'{arg}.npy'
    np.save(file_io.FileIO(f'{save_string}', 'w'), new_shape)
    del new_shape

# Run reshape function
reshape_images(sys.argv[1])

# Clear memory of namespace variables
gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how the disk could be full. When I check free -m after parallel throws the error, I have >120GB of available space on disk.

You need to do `df scratch/tmp` *before* GNU Parallel stops.

GNU Parallel opens temporary files in `--tmpdir`, removes them immediately, but keeps them open. This is to avoid that files need to be cleaned up if GNU Parallel is killed.

You will most likely discover a situation where:

- scratch/tmp is full
- there are no files in scratch/tmp

But as soon as GNU Parallel ends, the space will be free.

So if you only look at `df` *after* GNU Parallel has finished, you will not be looking at the time when the disk is full.

In other words: What you see is a 100% normal behaviour when `scratch/tmp` is too small.

Try setting `--tmpdir` to a dir with more available space.

Or try:

```
seq 100000000 | parallel -uj1 -N0 df scratch/tmp
```

while running your jobs and see the disk fill up.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this Ole Tange!